# Why does anyone prefer Metapost?

Tags: tikz-pgf, metapost

TikZ (together with its PGF backend) is the most widely used picture drawing tool by regulars here, having more than 50x as many questions as for Metapost, alongside a wealth of documentation and user support elsewhere.  TikZ is supported by several of the most popular TeX engines, while Metapost has native support only in LuaTeX, needing invocation as a separate program from other platforms.  And TikZ uses familiar TeX syntax, not requiring another macro-based language to be learned.

Yet Metapost has a band of loyal followers.  There are "traditional" reasons for this: Metapost is more "Knuthian", being derived from Knuth's Metafont and by report is Knuth's preferred tool; Metapost is rather older than TikZ, and so some prefer it for reasons of sticking with the better-understood tool.

Are there other reasons why users might prefer Metapost to TikZ?

Comment: I looked for thsi qn before asking and contrived to overlook an older qn, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34523/pgf-tikz-vs-metapost - I guess I would not have asked the question, although this question asks for advantages of MP over Tikz from the viewpoint of an MP user, not differences between the two.

Comment: Make no mistake that if you don't mind the dvips route it's as good as TikZ and sometimes even better because of the underlying PS engine. I've learned a lot after asking a similar question. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/fundamental-differences-pstricks-tikz-pgf-and-others

Comment: Also I need to say that MP,PSTricks and others have a certain *scientific vibe* to it and TikZ is much more graphics based and neutral when it comes to documentation. I think the manual is making a tremendous difference in terms of popularity. I couldn't resist :)

Comment: metapost has been used successfully in the development of new fonts.  i'm not sufficiently familiar with the details of tikz to know if this is possible, but i suspect that, even if it is, it's more difficult/complicated.

Comment: @barbara - Right.  Indeed, Latin Modern was developed using METATYPE1 (essentially some scripts, library support, and templates for turning Metapost figures into Type-1 fonts).  There's no reason I can think of why some similar script/template system could not be put together for PGF, though I guess that PGF does not map onto Postscript in as clean a way as Metapost.  If that's true, that's an answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here are a few reasons why I use MetaPost.

- MetaPost is tightly integrated into ConTeXt
- MetaPost is by an order of magnitudes faster than TikZ
- MetaPost is included in the TeX backend (in LuaTeX). That's one
  of the reasons where the speed gain comes from. Not being
  implemented in TeX is another.
- I created some custom MetaPost macros ages ago which I still use
  and there is no reason to port it to a TikZ or to another package.
- I find the MetaPost syntax easier to understand than TikZ
- It has a brilliant manual (this does in no way imply that the Tikz manual is inferior)

Comment: The manual I was referring to is [the MetaFun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-s.pdf). It's not strictly MetaPost, but large parts are applicable to plain MetaPost as well.

Comment: gmp package (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gmp) integrates Metapost with LaTeX too. It also lets you use your LaTeX document parameters inside Metapost code.

Comment: How about the capability of 3D drawing and  plotting?

Comment: Is there a good tutorial for drawing commutative diagrams with metapost?

Answer (score 11):

I don't know about `Metapost`. I use the `Metapost` inspired language `Asymptote`. I preferred it because I felt that it's

- More general-purpose
- `C++`-like and object-oriented (thus a soft learning curve for me)

That said, I still believe `PGF/Tikz` is very powerful and I do use `circuitikz` for circuit diagrams rather than draw all the electronic elements from scratch in `Asymptote`. I only wish I had more time to learn `PGF/Tikz`. I think the deciding factor for me was time.

**Update**

For what it's worth, I finally found the time to learn some TikZ and I totally get where you're coming from now: TikZ is a godsend!

Comment: I actually went in the opposite direction: I learned TikZ first, and then switched partially to Asymptote because of its 3D capabilities. But I still use TikZ sometimes.

Answer (score 7):

i expect that many metapost users are ex-metafont-users; if you're fluent in metafont, metapost's probably as good as anything.  remember that pgf came along really rather recently; it's clear that it's a *good* _thing_, since its adoption has been exponentially fast, but old habits die hard.

(including my habit of almost never drawing anything, which dates back to the 1980s...)

Comment: I learnt Metapost without knowing Metafont, it's a very natural language indeed. In fact with Metapost you are able to do easy things quickly, and hard things easily, once you have spent some time in learning it.